# SQL Server cumulative SUM of a DATEDIFF into a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get a cumulative SUM of a DATEDIFF into a percentage from some basic data I have, here is a small snapshot:

```
ID     IIn                       IOut
AB123  2015-11-06 15:24:44.057   2015-11-14 01:00:00.000
QA565  2015-10-27 20:12:19.753   2015-11-06 03:00:00.000
UN555  2015-12-29 06:29:23.417   2016-01-03 08:00:00.000
LG602  2015-08-07 16:52:13.573   2015-08-11 03:00:00.000
```

ETC ETC

I then use DATEDIFF to get a number of days:

```
SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(hour, IIn, IOut)/24.0 IDays
FROM TimeTable
```

Which gives me:

```
ID     IDays
AB123  7.416666
QA565  9.291666
UN555  5.083333
LG602  3.458333
```

What I want is a count of `ID`'S split by their `IDay`'s (rounded down) with a cumulative % from lowest `IDay`'s to highest like so:

```
ID     IDays  IDaysPer
LG602  3      12.5
UN555  5      33.33
AB123  7      62.49
QA565  9      100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a couple of windowed aggregates, placing your original query in a CTE for convenience (A subquery would also work):

```
declare @timeTable table (ID char(5) not null, IIn datetime not null,
                          IOut datetime not null)
insert into @timeTable(ID,IIn,IOut) values
('AB123','2015-11-06T15:24:44.057','2015-11-14T01:00:00.000'),
('QA565','2015-10-27T20:12:19.753','2015-11-06T03:00:00.000'),
('UN555','2015-12-29T06:29:23.417','2016-01-03T08:00:00.000'),
('LG602','2015-08-07T16:52:13.573','2015-08-11T03:00:00.000')

;With Diffs as (
    SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(hour, IIn, IOut)/24.0 IDays
    FROM @timeTable
)
select
    *,
    (
      SUM(IDays) OVER (ORDER BY IDays, ID)
      /
      SUM(IDays) OVER ()
    ) * 100 as IDaysPer
from
    Diffs
order by IDays
```

Note that I couldn't quite make sense of your "rounded down" requirement but you should be able to use any common rounding technique wrapped around the appropriate calculation. So my outputs don't quite match yours:

```
ID    IDays                                   IDaysPer
----- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
LG602 3.458333                                13.696300
UN555 5.083333                                33.828300
AB123 7.416666                                63.201300
QA565 9.291666                                100.000000
```

Comment: @Matt - try adding another column to the `ORDER BY` clause within the first `OVER` to enable it to know which way to break ties (You may also want to add same to the final `ORDER BY` to change display order)

Comment: I'm going to delete my comments for clarity for future readers

Answer (score 1):

Here you go : Output matches with yours...

```
        create table #TEMp
(ID VARCHAR(100)
,IIn datetime
,IOut datetime
)


insert into #temp(ID,IIn,IOut) values
('AB123','2015-11-06T15:24:44.057','2015-11-14T01:00:00.000'),
('QA565','2015-10-27T20:12:19.753','2015-11-06T03:00:00.000'),
('UN555','2015-12-29T06:29:23.417','2016-01-03T08:00:00.000'),
('LG602','2015-08-07T16:52:13.573','2015-08-11T03:00:00.000')

select ID,IDays AS Idays,ROUND(CAST(SUM(IDays) OVER(ORDER BY IDays) AS FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(IDays)OVER() AS FLOAT) * 100,2) AS IdaysPer
from
(
select *,ROUND(DATEDIFF(hour, IIn, IOut)/24,0) IDays
from #TEMP
)T
```

[image]

Comment: Except that's not what the OP asked. Getting the `IDays` is part of the problem as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Added that as well, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @Matt : Hope this helps

Comment: calculating *IDays* is part of the problem. This query doesn't do that

Comment: Matt already has that logic : SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(hour, IIn, IOut)/24.0 IDays
FROM TimeTable

Comment: Well I have edited again and added the logic to calculate even IDays in my query.

Answer (score 1):

Consider TimeTable has already the data

```
WITH t1 (ID, IDays)
AS (
    SELECT ID, DATEDIFF(hour, IIn, IOut) / 24.0 AS IDays
    FROM TimeTable
)
SELECT 
    ID, FLOOR(IDays), 
    (FLOOR(IDays) / (SELECT SUM(FLOOR(IDays)) FROM t1 t2 WHERE t1.IDays <= t2.IDays)) * 100.0 AS IDaysPer
FROM t1
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```